# Well Is this facebook app following all the rules(TOS)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Well I found this app (just a demo app for sale)
http://apps.facebook.com/horoscope-demo/

But before buying I am confused with:
This app

Asks to post on wall at first use

Shows advertisement dialog at app entry

Shows send request dialog at entry

and also has auto daily post on the user's wall (after permission)

Is there any violations of facebook tos?
There were some rules not to show dialog, send request dialog as far as I remember.
plus
is  auto wall posting(even after approval) still possible or allowed by facebook?
I didn't test the daily auto post but can it still do it?

Thanks for replies Fb app developers.
As fb developer these questions are pretty useful.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing not software.

Comment: Pardon me Sometimes I get confused about these section. My intention was to post it under facebook(neither licensing nor software) so I tagged it using those tags...if it not under proper section please feel free to move it. Thank you very much.Hope somebody gonna answer it. Thanks